# Passing values from resource file to list picker in wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have array collectoon of 200 items,I given keys and values in resource files and kept the keys in an array .I want to pass this array to list picker

In this manner:

```
         String[] countries={"In","Aus","Bng","pak",..............};

        for(int i=0;i<countries.length;i++ )
                       {
          //I need to add in this manner but resources have only static strings
          countrieslistpicker.Items.Add(Resources.countries[i])
                       }
```

so how can i dynamically get from resorce files .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Resource Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx)'s GetString() Method to access items in the resource files.

Answer (score 0):

Try following approach

```
    for(int i=0;i<countries.length;i++ )
    {
       var countryName = AppResources.ResourceManager.GetString(Resources.countries[i])
        countrieslistpicker.Items.Add(countryName);
    }
```